# Add text from a variable to href link inside actor tag

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have 15 actor tags with href links like this

```
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf"></a>
```

As these PDF's are updated frequently and I don't want to cache them browser, I thought of adding updated Date at the end of this href link as `?date=updateDate` by storing the updateDate in a variable like

```
    <script>
        updateDate = "20210624";
    </script>
```

I thought of updating my `href` link as it might add date to the url at the end

```
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date="+updateDate></a>
```

But it is not working. I did my research on this and got to know that I need to update the url seperately for each of the 15 links. Is there any way that I can do it in the way I can store the date value and use it for all 15 links without changing everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(e => {
  e.href += new Date().getTime();
})
```

```html
<a href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date='>link</a>
<a href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date='>link</a>
<a href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date='>link</a>
```

If you want to only change the `href` of certain anchor tags, assign them a class name:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.nocache').forEach(e => {
  e.href += new Date().getTime();
})
```

```html
<a class="nocache" href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date='>link</a>
<a href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf'>link</a>
<a class="nocache" href='https://www.w3schools.com/temp.pdf?date='>link</a>
```

Comment: What if I have some other `href` elements which I don't want to add this date?

Comment: @user147504 Glad to help :)